# when springmvc's requestmapping with chinese ,happen an error?

Tags: java, eclipse, spring-mvc

in springmvc when I use request mapping like:

> ```
> /home/tag/{tag}
> ```

the 'tag' accept as a String; 
when I transmit a chinese word to 'tag', such as:

> ```
> **/home/tag/中文**
> ```

it works,
but when I use the same url, just change chinese to another one,
such as:

> ```
> /home/tag/旅行
> ```

I am getting 404 error without any output in eclipse. I'm new to learn springmvc ，I'll appreciate it if you can help me to improve.

Comment: You can encode your request path in js and decode the param `tag` in controller.

Comment: thank you for spend time on me . I still got that error .Temporary ,to solve it  I  use a form to pass the 'tag'  instead.